# symmetric group as a subgroup of general linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-groups

Is the symmetric group $S_n$ a normal subgroup of the general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$? We regard $\sigma\in S_n$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by permuting the coordinates $\sigma(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(x_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,x_{\sigma(n)})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $$\pmatrix{1 &1 \\ 0 &1}\pmatrix{0 &1 \\ 1 &0}\pmatrix{1 &1 \\ 0 &1}^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 &0 \\ 1 &-1}$$
is not a permutation matrix.